# CSS - Different Style on first class element of a page

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

I´m trying to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1743291

I want to give the first element of a class a different style from the other elements using the same class.

So I created something like this following the workaround from the post above:

```
.kn-menu > .control.has-addons {
border: 1px solid red;}

.kn-menu > .control.has-addons ~ .control.has-addons {
border: none;}
```

But this is not working for me.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my approuch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `first-of-type` pseudo class:

```css
  .test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .test:first-of-type{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: This is the method I need to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1743291

Comment: without seeing your code, it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have three divs within a parent section like this:

```
<section class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</section>
```

And on your CSS you have styles for those divs with class name "child":

```
.parent .child{
    border:0;
}
```

You can give particular properties to the first div like this:

```
.parent .child:first-child{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Or select child what you want:

```
.parent .child:nth-child(3){
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Did not work. I need to do something like this in order to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1743291

Comment: Well, i don't understand what you need...in the link you passed explains very good how to do it by > and ~ selectors.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correct you just want to difference the first element. I think that solution can be use pseudo class first-of-type

HTML

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.item:first-of-type {
  color: blue
}
```

https://codepen.io/smil3cz/pen/GRjYyyL